# Custom Sort Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and trying to implement a custom sort function for list for learning purpose. Can anyone guide why the below code is returning [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Update: Thank you guys. I have updated my code with the print statements in between to see where the code is buggy. However I still cant get my my head around how to proceed from here. I have added the y variable as well to compare x and to store the smaller value when the inner loop goes on. Can you please provide some hint?

```
a=[1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]
a=[1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]

x=int()  ## Variable to store the smaller value while comparing the list with its clone 

d=a[:] ## Duplicate list of a to compare. 
c=[] ## Sorted list


def sorts(list):

  for i in a: ###############Loops over each item in list a    
    y=i
    for q in d: #######Compares each item from **list a** with **list d**
      global x
    
      if i<=q:   ## If item of list a is less than of list d (duplicate of a). Then x
        x=i
        if y>x:  
          y=x

      elif i>q:  ##
        x=q
        if y>q:
          y=q

      
      print('X :', x)

    
    c.append(y)
    print('C: ', c)
    try:
      d.remove(y)
      print('D: ', d, '\n')
    except:
      pass
    
  return (c)

sorts(a)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? Could you add line-by-line comments in the post to explain your logic? (It might help you too.) Have you tried adding e.g. print statements (or using a debugger) to see how state changes during the loop?

Comment: Your inner loop will always end up setting `x` to `1` in the final iteration and then you append that value to the result. However, there are several errors in your code other than that, so you should probably do what @AKX suggests and you may find some of the problems with your code.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have updated my code with the print statements in between to see where the code is buggy. However I still cant get my my head around how to proceed from here. I have added the **y** variable as well to compare x and to store the smaller value when the inner loop goes on. Can you please provide some hint?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def sorts(list):
    for idx, value in enumerate(a):
        for i in range(idx+1, len(a)):
            if value>a[i]:
                a[idx], a[i] = a[i], a[idx]
                value = a[idx]
    return (a)
  
print(sorts(a))
```

Comment: How does this answer explain what is wrong with the initial code?

Comment: [1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 1]
[1]

Comment: This is what pop is doing to list 'd'
and every time the x is set to 1 so the first index of list is removed each time.
in sorting we compare the first value with every other value and check if there is any value greater than the current value, and swap if there is. Which was not in the original code